# Ruby's File.exist? not seeing network files right away?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a class with some methods to either copy or encode music files from a playlist. Everything works fine except, randomly, File.exists? reports a file doesn't exist when indeed it does. Running the app again produces either no errors, or reports a different couple files missing.

```
 def sync
  unless File.exist?(@source_file)
    puts "Does not exist: #{@source_file}"
    yield 1.0
    return
  end
...
```

This sync method is being called in thread pool and the source file locations are on a local lan smb share. The check for existence shouldn't need to be in a Mutex or anything, correct? Any ideas what's going on and how to prevent it?
THANKS!

Comment: If you are creating the file from another thread, then maybe this is called too soon? Hard to say without seeing more code

Comment: Are you sure you're testing the full path? Are you sure you've sequenced your operations correctly?

Comment: you could always add it to a do while loop and keep checking if it exists until it does, you would probably want to setup a timeout though. - ruby is synchronous, so it runs and executed the next script waiting for the commend to finish until the next one fires. if the operating system isnt updating its data fast enough you just have to introduce something to make ruby wait longer. `sleep(x_number_of_seconds)` is another option, but i like the looping option better.

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone. To clarify, I'm NOT creating the files, they are static on a network share and I am using properly escaped, full paths. Since @alilland mentioned looping (I was considering this), it sounds like this isn't something horribly uncommon. I didn't know if there was some formal Ruby lexicon for handling slow file systems like this such as checking for the file system availability first then the file. I didn't see it talked about much so it bothered me that this could be a problem for any file IO if there's a chance of one's script being pointed at files on a network.

Comment: I added a line `File.exist?(@source_file)` before the unless statement basically doing the exist check twice and it eliminates the random false file missing flag. Indicating the network resources aren't able to keep up with the check for the existence of the network file.